# How do I Connect my Android device remotely using TCPIP?

Tags: android, tcp

I am new in Android development and currently I face some issues regarding connect my Android device remotely using TCPIP, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp  see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb tcpip 5555
set /p ip=android device ip: 
ECHO connect to %ip%
adb connect %ip%
set /p ip=done:
```

Answer (score 1):

connect your mobile using adb firest then

```
adb start tcpip 5000
```

this will restart the adb in tcpip:5000 port, then,

```
adb connect 192.168.1.23
```